# Unity Intellisense with Visual Studio Code - Intellisense is mostly working except methods, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I've recently gotten back to game development and I would rather use vscode over visual studio for convenience.

Now Intellisense is mostly working, but methods won't show up.
For example:[image]

As you can see, intellisense seems to be working fine here, but when I try doing something like this (picture is taken from visual studio community):
[image]

It won't work:

[image]

It might be obvious but I cant pinpoint why it's not working.
I tried googling it, but to no avail.

Any clues?

Comment: after you typed **onTrig** did you hit enter for it to complete ?

Comment: @joel64 What do you  mean?
In vscode it did not even prompt the auto completion.
Im currently editing the second picture's description, but to clarify the second picture is from visual studio community and not code, it;s just an example of what I expected to see in vscode

Comment: After more researching I arrived at this post:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/
Which explains why some IDEs have trouble with those commands, the question is whether its possible to get auto completion for them without downloading some kind of a snippet plugin?

Comment: oh sorry my bad , sorry if this sounds stupid but is visual studio set up in your external tools in unity editor ? ...basically this > https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-with-visual-studio-fix.836599/

Comment: @joel64 Yes it is, also I tried regenrationg the csproj and sln files, I made sure I have vscode in my package manager and tried changing the mono settings in the c# extension to "always".

I also didnt see one picture of someone having this kind of auto completion with the methods, only with other parts of unity's library.

As far as I understand, those commands won't show under unity files and therefore won't be available to even intellisense, but why visual studio community is able to show them? im kind of confused...

Comment: im not sure but i hope you have Visual Studio plugin for Unity installed ?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code doesn't autocomplete methods like `Update`, `Awake` and `OnTriggerEnter` in MonoBehaviours because they are "magical" methods that are not `virtual` or `abstract`, but you can install an extension that contains those methods as snippets.
I tried it but didn't like it.
You may like it though: [Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets).

Answer (score 0):

Once I was stuck in the same situation.
Installing extension

> [Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets)

worked for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31987697)